# What is the correct way to encodeURIcomponent non utf-8 characters and decodes them accordingly?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, urldecode, encodeuricomponent

I have a Javascript bookmarklet that uses `encodeURIcomponent` to pass the URL of the current page to the server side, and then use `urldecode` on the server side to get the characters back.

The problem is, when the encoded character is not in utf-8 (for my case it's gb2312, but it could be something else), and when the server does the `urldecode`, the decoded character become squares. Which, obviously, isn't what it looked like before the encoding.

It's a bookmarklet, input could be anything, so I can't just define "encode as gb2312" in the js, or "decode as gb2312" in the php scripts.

So, is there a correct way of using `encodeURIcomponent` which passes the character encoding together with the contents, and then the decoding can pick the right encoding to decode it?

Answer (score 0):

For encoding of browsers, especially for GB2312 charset, check the following docs (in Chinese) first

- http://ued.taobao.com/blog/2011/08/26/encode-war/
- http://www.ruanyifeng.com/blog/2010/02/url_encoding.html

For your case, `%C8%B7%B6%A8` is actually generated from the GB2312 form of `'\u786e\u5b9a'`. This occurs normally on (legacy?) versions of IE and FF, when user directly inputs Chinese character in location bar,
<del>*Or* you're using non-standard link from page content which does not perform IRI to URI encoding at all and just render binary string like `'/tag/\xc8\xb7\xb6\xa8'`(douban.com used to have this usage for tags, now they're using correct URI encoding in UTF8).</del> not quite sure because cannot reproduce in Chrome, maybe test in FF and IE, part about douban is true.

Actually, the correct output of `encodeURIComponent` should be

```
> encodeURIComponent('%C8%B7%B6%A8')
  "%25C8%25B7%25B6%25A8"
```

Thus in server side, when an unquoted string contains non-ascii bytes, you'd better to leave the string as it is, here `'%C8%B7%B6%A8'`.

Also, you *could* check in client side to apply `encodeURIComponent` again on a value that contains `%XX` where XX is larger than `0x7F`. I'm not quite sure whether this against RFC 2396 though.

写英文好累啊，不过还是要入乡随俗～

Comment: nice source, I'll check them out:)

Answer (score 0):

Using `escape()` and then translate the characters to [numeric character reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference) before sending them to server.

From [MDN escape() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape):

> The hexadecimal form for characters, whose code unit value is 0xFF or
>   less, is a two-digit escape sequence: %xx. For characters with a
>   greater code unit, the four-digit format %uxxxx is used.

Thus, it's easy to translate the output of `escape()` to numeric character reference by using a simple `replace()` statement:

```
escape(input_value).replace(/%u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, '&#x$1;');
```

Or, if your server-side language only supports decimal entities, use:

```
escape(input_value).replace(/%u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/g, function(m0, m1) {
                return '&#' + parseInt(m1, 16) + ';';
};
```

**Example code in PHP**

`client.html` <sub>*(file encoding: GB2312)*</sub>:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="gb2312">
    <script>
    function processForm(form) {
        console.log('BEFORE:', form.test.value);
        form.test.value = escape(form.test.value).replace(/%u(\w{4})/g, function(m0, m1) {
            return '&#' + parseInt(m1, 16) + ';';
        });
        console.log('AFTER:', form.test.value);
        return true;
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="server.php" onsubmit="return processForm(this);">
      <input type="text" name="test" value="确定">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

`server.php`:

```
<?php
echo '<script>console.log("', 
     $_REQUEST['test'], ' --> ', 
     mb_decode_numericentity($_REQUEST['test'], array(0x80, 0xffff, 0, 0xffff), 'UTF-8'),
     '");</script>';
?>
```